# Send a form to a sub declared in a DLL files

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, dll

I'm trying to create (finally) my own DLL files to some code that I will use constantly in a new project, I'm using Visual Basic 2010

I created the DLL correctly but I got a problem with a sub have the code `Me.Handle`

I don't know how to send the "me" to my sub

This is my sub (from an example in msdn)

```
Sub Start_Detection()

    Dim di As New DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE

    di.dbcc_size = CUInt(Marshal.SizeOf(GetType(DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE)))
    di.dbcc_devicetype = DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE
    di.dbcc_reserved = 0

    di.dbcc_classguid = Guid.Parse("{88BAE032-5A81-49f0-BC3D-A4FF138216D6}")
    di.dbcc_name = Nothing

    hDevNotify = RegisterDeviceNotification(Me.Handle, di, DEVICE_NOTIFY_WINDOW_HANDLE)


End Sub
```

When I put that inside a DLL, I don't know how to send the `Me` because in the DLL project says that "Me" isn't a member of my DLL project.

If I declare the sub as `Sub Start_Detection(ByRef Form)` or `Sub Start_Detection(ByVal Form)` the DLL project works ok, but when I call it from the windows form project a "Null Reference Exception" happen.

Is not possible to send forms as arguments in Visual Basic 2010 ?

Thanks!

---

Edit: I'm calling the sub in this way

```
   Private Sub Frm_Config_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        MyDLL.Start_Detection(Me)

    End Sub
```

Comment: You *must* use a valid window handle to receive notifications.  Of course it is possible to pass objects of type Form to another method, just don't pass one that is Nothing.

Comment: Do you mean the `di.dbcc_name = nothing` part? This code is part of a bigger one that works (was my first attempt to detect hardware change). And well How to pass the form to the sub inside the DLL is what I can't figure out how to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might also want to consider using the following naming convention for the parameter

```
Sub Start_Detection (ByVal sender As System.Object)
```

or

```
Sub Start_Detection (ByVal handle As IntPtr)
```

When your calling the method, pass the handle value to the Class method

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    If Me.IsHandleCreated Then
        RecieveHandle.Start_Detection(Me.Handle)
    End If
End Sub
```

Then once your in the class module, you can do a common trick to confirm the variable has been supplied and don't pass a reference to the whole form via the "Me" (VB) or "This" (C#) variable.

```
Public Class RecieveHandle
Public Shared Sub Start_Detection(ByVal sender As System.Object)
    If sender Is Nothing Then
        Throw New ArgumentException("Method requires sender parameter to be supplied")
    End If
    If Not TypeOf (sender) Is IntPtr Then
        Throw New ArgumentException("Method requires a valid pointer (handle) to the form.")
    End If

    Dim myFormHandle As IntPtr = CType(sender, IntPtr)

    Debug.Print(myFormHandle.ToInt64.ToString)
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: The use of `Sub Start_Detection (ByVal sender As System.Object)` doesn't give me any error in the editor (the other one does), but still give me an error when I try to run the project using `MyClass.Start_Detection(Me)` inside the `load` Method, it still give me an "System.NullReferenceException". I added the code in my main question just in case. Thanks

Comment: I've added a modification to include Me.IsHandleCreated to ensure the value is available.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Jamie . I really need to look further into the access rights, I needed to change all my subs in my DLL file to `Public Shared` to get those working.

Answer (score 1):

`Me` belongs to a form not a dll. If you pass the IntPtr you will be fine.

```
Sub Start_Detection(ptr As IntPtr)
 Dim di As New DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE
 di.dbcc_size = CUInt(Marshal.SizeOf(GetType(DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE)))
 di.dbcc_devicetype = DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE
 di.dbcc_reserved = 0

 di.dbcc_classguid = Guid.Parse("{88BAE032-5A81-49f0-BC3D-A4FF138216D6}")
 di.dbcc_name = Nothing

 hDevNotify = RegisterDeviceNotification(ptr, di, DEVICE_NOTIFY_WINDOW_HANDLE)
End Sub
```

Usage:

```
Start_Detection(Me.Handle)
```

Comment: Thanks, I needed to used Jaimie Clayton `As System` to get rid of the errors in the editor. But Still have problems calling the sub and sending the form inside the "on load" method

Comment: @distante, it's the way you use it.

Comment: How Should I send the form to the sub then? Using the name itself in the load method VB tells me that can't reference a form inside the form itself, that I need to use `Me, when I use `Me` an "System.NullReferenceException" appears. Thanks for the help

Comment: The parameter is of type `IntPtr` and the forms `Handle` is an `IntPtr` so how about that example above - did you try that?

Comment: Yes, I'm using MyDLL.StartDetection(Me.Handle) inside the form_load and I'm still getting a `NullReferenceException`